# onclick doesnt working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova

Unfortunately work in [Phonegap](https://cordova.apache.org) no javascript onclick functions. Like this one:

```
<a onClick="getThis(1,3,7);" type="button" >Take this 137</a>
```

the buttons are loaded dynamically after the init load:

```
var answers = '';

$.each( questions, function(index, value) {    
    answers = answers + '<li><a onclick="setAnswer('+ level + ',' + index + ',' +  player +');" type="button">' + value + '</a></li>';
  });  

$('#answers').html(answers);
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Can you elaborate on your question a bit more please? I have trouble understanding the problem.

Comment: what happens when you click the button? also, could you post your `getThis()` function

Comment: when I click the button nothing happens. In browsers the function is called correctly, but unfortunately not as with PhoneGap compiled app on the phone.

Answer (score -1):

You have an error with upper case in `onclick`. Try this :

```
<a onclick="getThis(1,3,7);" type="button" >Take this 137</a>
```

Comment: That's invalid. Event attributes in HTML are case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't working with phone gap. In Browser works boths.

Comment: @HeikovonMettelsiefen, are you waiting for the `deviceready` event in your code?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 yes! But the onclick-function button wil generate after init load. i have to update my general post.

Comment: @HeikovonMettelsiefen, I do not know what "init load" is.